# Payments dialog USD vs Credits

Tags: javascript, facebook-credits

Following the newly released API where you pass

dev_purchase_params: {'oscif': true}

along with the other normal params to the FB.ui payments dialog results in some inconsistent behaviour.  I was wondering if I was doing something wrong.

If I have enough credits balance to pay for an item, then the payments dialog will show the item price in credits (ie.  Purchase XYZ - Price:10 credits).  But if I don't have enough credits, then it shows it in USD (or whatever currency the user has set as their default).  For example, if the item costs 10 dollars (100 credits) and I only have a 50 credits balance, then it will show "Purchase XYZ - Price:$10 USD" along with payment options and such.

Is there a way to always show USD(or local currency)?  Otherwise, our in game storefront is a little inconsistent with the payment dialog.  If we price everything with local currency prices but the payment dialog pops up asking for Credits, this will confuse the end user.